# backquote in system() function

Tags: c, system, backquote

I have a problem with backquotes (it seems) in system() function in C.
This is my request :

```
snprintf (check_cmd, sizeof (check_cmd), "[ $(echo -n '%.*s' | cksum | cut -d' ' -f1) -eq %" PRIu32 " ]", (cfi_sys_int)data_array[i].size, data_array[i].bytes, crc_32 );
system (check_cmd);
```

I check the value of snprintf and system() return value but it doesn't return the good value

Comment: It seems your example does not contain any backquotes. Is that the problem?

Comment: "it doesn't return the good value" - which function?  what value?  What is the full string in `check_cmd` after `snprintf()`?

Comment: For the return value, I should expect a 0 if it works, right ? but it's not the case.
Then I put back quote and replace the "$(" and "). But it doesn't work yet.
In fact, I've read that some shell doesn't support the "$(". 
Then I've checked the value of check_cmd, it's the good one.

Comment: Read the documentation for `snprintf` again. That's not what it returns.

Comment: This is not snprintf() value return.
I know that snprintf return the number of bytes written and I check it, this is good. 
But when I put check_cmd in system(), system return a value != 0.